# ReactJS access "this" in a callback

Tags: reactjs, this

Within a callback, I'd like to get the props passed to a component but can't get it through `this.props` as `this` is undefined there.

Here is a simplified example:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({  
  options:{
    componentFunction: function(c) {
      console.log(this.props.myProp); //this references to the options here, not the component itself 
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <OtherComponent options={ this.options } />
    );
  }
});
```

And I pass the props this way:

```
<MyComponent myProp={"x"};
```

Would appreciate any help,
Thanks.

Comment: I would strongly advice to move to ES6 syntax. With Arrow Functions this would be no problem.

Comment: thanks for the advice, will do for my next project!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `componentFunction` has its own scope.  You need to bind it, which you can do by adding the following method to `MyComponent`:

```
componentWillMount: function() {
    this.options.componentFunction = this.options.componentFunction.bind(this);
}
```

**Update**: If you're using ES6 classes, the above should go in the constructor instead.

However, it may be nicer to use arrow functions instead, which do not define their own scope and so will inherit `this` from the parent scope.

```
options:{
    componentFunction: () => console.log(this.props.myProp)
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @James, this fixed my issue. Updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/gdc2bpw7/

Answer (score 2):

Use `this.options.bind(this)` instead of `this.options` to access `this` inside the function.

Or use ES6 syntax - `options = () = {...}`.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. That makes sense but when I try to add this code, I get the following error message: **this.options.bind is not a function**. I quickly created a fiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/ayp52sck/

Comment: Yeah, sorry - take a look to answer of @James Brierley - you need to use bind accordinaly to the function, not to the object,